# How to mak creditcard cvv with optional length

Tags: jquery, masking

I need to mask my creditcard cvv with optional length 3 or 4 .

How can i do this?

My code

```
$("#cvv").mask("9999");
```

I need to take value with 3 or 4 length.

Thanks

Comment: The Mask plugin has [quite extensive documentation](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) on how to make fields optional -- does the docs not specify what you need?

Comment: Please mention in your question which plugin you are using for input field masks. (Also add it to the tags, which will direct more people with interest/experience of that plugin to this question.)

Answer (score -1):

Make you are "cvv" input text box type as "password" like below.

```
<input type="password" id="cvv" name="" value="9999"/>.
```

Input data will convert automatically masked. To get value from the input box:

```
$("#cvv").val();=>9999
```

Comment: am working on masking input not like hiding data .Check this pleasehttp://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/